# Is there any easy way to verify and decode a JWT in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jwt

Is there any library / NPM module / code sample to verify and decode a JWT in React Native?

I know I can do it manually. But I was hoping something like [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) existed. (It does not work in React Native.)

https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode only decodes but does not verify.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [RSA-Sign JavaScript Library](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign) that does what you want, though it uses some rather large and slow crypto libraries written in pure JS.

If you want to work a little to get a simpler and faster result, use the [Wep Crypto API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#subtlecrypto-interface) to get the browser to verify the signature for you. The exact code will depend on the key algorithm and format, but essentially you decode the base64url-encoded signature at the bottom of the JWT, then you call `crypto.subtle.importKey` with `["verify"]` as the last argument (passing the key in JWK format or whatever else you can get), and then you use the resulting key to call `crypto.subtle.verify`. You'll need to turn the (decoded) token's signature into an ArrayBuffer, which can be accomplished with:

```
buffer = new Uint8Array([...signature].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
```

Avoid fetching the key over the same network and just before verifying the signature (if the key is referenced by the 'jku' or given in the 'jwk' header fields of the token), since verifying its integrity is rather tricky inside the browser. Better if you can hardcode it in your source code after manual checking.